# Android NDK debugging on HTC Incredible S

Tags: debugging, android-ndk

I have recently had to change my work Android phone to an HTC Incredible S to use for Android NDK debugging. Unfortunately, the `ndk-gdb` script fails to attach the debugger, coming up with the error `run-as: Package my.package has corrupt installation`. I have tried all the usual fixes - uninstalling and reinstalling the apk, cleaning and rebuilding in Eclipse - several times, but to no avail. Also, I know the project is set up properly for debugging as I have been doing so successfully for a few weeks on a Nexus S.

Has anyone had any success with Android NDK on the Incredible S? And if so, did you have to do anything particular? I realise it may be necessary to root the phone and change the permissions of /data/data, but I want to avoid this if at all possible.

Thanks

EDIT: Okay, I've also tried the HTC Desire S, with similar results. Could anyone tell me of a phone they've used successfully for NDK multi-threaded debugging without rooting that's not the Nexus S? I've tried the Galaxy S II - the debugger connected but none of the breakpoints were hit - I think this is down to the Tegra chip at its core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research with various phones, it seems that HTC Sense (or something that HTC add) changes something deep within Android that makes run-as fail (as it is so picky about the filesystem due to its SUID bit - fair enough). So if this helps anyone else - I would avoid trying to use an HTC for debugging (rooting might help, but I haven't tested it).

Phones that I have had success with are:

- Google Nexus S and the Google Nexus One (I'm thinking any Google-branded phone with stock Android on will work).
- Sony Xperia Play.